# How to instantiate objects for the length of an audio clip

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, vector, instantiation

My overall goal is to have a script that constantly generates an object along the y axis until a piece of audio stops playing. The object in question are "starfields" which are groups of stars to create the effect of outer-space. This can be done easily and I already know how to do this using a constant velocity. The hardest part for me is to generate these objects with an object that gets faster and faster.

To elaborate on this, there is a rocket that goes faster and faster using the scripts below, it multiplies a constant speed which I set (10) with the movement from a Vector3. It has an acceleration of 0.25 as you can see in the code. The idea is that the rocket keeps on flying until the audio ends and the stars stop spawning and the game ends. The rocket gradually gets faster and faster so I can't just hard-code it in.

Below is my code for the rocket and the star spawn script.

This is just one way around the problem, I have spent quite a while trying different things but nothing seems to work. I have a feeling there's an easier way around this problem.

Star spawn code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class StarSpawn : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    public Transform Object;
    AudioSource Music;
    float MusicClipLength;
    float distance;
    void Start()
    {
        Music = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        AudioClip MusicClip;
        MusicClip = Music.clip;
        MusicClipLength = Music.clip.length;   //time


        distance = ((((0.5f * 0.25f) * (MusicClipLength * MusicClipLength))));   //distance
        float RoundedDistance = (float)Mathf.Floor(distance);   //rounding
        for (int i = 0; i <= RoundedDistance; i++)   //generation loop
        {
            Instantiate(Object, new Vector3(0, i * 1750.0f, 500), 
Quaternion.Euler(-90, 0, 90));
        }
    }
 }
```

Rocket code (some of this is irrelevant)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public bool Launch = false;
    private Rigidbody rb;
    public int Speed;
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    public void LaunchStart()
    {
        Launch = true;
    }


    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float altitude = (rb.position.y);
        if (Launch == true)
        {
            float moveHorizontal = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.25f, 0.0f);
            if (altitude > 0)
            { 
                rb.AddForce(movement * Speed);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

0.25 is the acceleration for everything and 10 is the set public speed for instance.

I realise this is quite a big problem is solve so even if someone recognises an easier way around the problem I would much appreciate any advice.

### Edit

My actual problem is that the stars over spawn, way too much. So when the audio has finished, there are still lots of stars left.

Comment: what exactly is the issue? the stars don't spawn? the rocket doesn't accelerate?

Comment: Yeah sorry, forgot to mention that. The problem is that the stars over spawn, way too much.

Answer (score 1):

Using coroutines would probably be a good choice here. With that, you could then use the speed of the rocket to determine the time delay between spawning stars:

```
float totaltime;

void Start()
{
    Music = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    AudioClip MusicClip;
    MusicClip = Music.clip;
    MusicClipLength = Music.clip.length;   //time

    distance = ((((0.5f * 0.25f) * (MusicClipLength * MusicClipLength))));   //distance
    float RoundedDistance = (float)Mathf.Floor(distance);   //rounding
    StartCoroutine(Spawner());
}

void IEnumerator Spawner()
{
    totaltime += Time.deltaTime;
    while (totaltime < MusicClipLength)
    {
        Instantiate(Object, new Vector3(0, i * 1750.0f, 500), Quaternion.Euler(-90, 0, 90));
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(rocketspeedFactor); // you should mess around with this value to get the spawning frequency correct. 
        // would be good to retrieve the speed from the rocket and multiple by some factor
    }

}
```